# Matplotlib notebook magic in Jupyter notebook partial plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, visualization

The first command in my Jupyter notebook is the %matplotlib notebook. This has been working fine but curiously the figures being drawn today are only partial plots. (The inline option without interactivity display complete plots).

When I pan, I can see more sections of the image.

I would like to see the entire plot and I am not sure what has caused this change in display

When image is first displayed it appears like this:
[Image created upon running the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISLk9.png)

After panning it appears like this:

[New section of image displayed upon panning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYcpo.png)

NOTE: This started to occur after updating to Matplotlib version 3.3.0.
For the current time I have reverted to Matplotlib version 3.1.0. But if the latest has some dependencies that I am missing which is causing the issue, I would like to learn how to figure those out.

I do not receive any errors or warnings upon import matplotlib or pyplot when working with 3.3.0

Comment: Dear S Talkar, I believe that your problem comes from the changes in your  backend libraries, which are made during the Matplotlib upgrade. Myself included faced a similar issue not so long ago. The downgrade won't easily solve the changes applied. An upgrade of the backends might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Philipe. I have been using pip to install and upgrade packages. I installed Anaconda and it came with a newer version of matplotlib and I have witnessed no issues so far.

Comment: I too have the exact same issue, and that was on a new installation. seems like a bug to report to me.